# set background screen blurr when running progressbar in android

Tags: android

Any one know how to set background blurr when progressbar wheel is running in andorid. I want that screen looks like blurr when circular wheel progress bar is running and no interaction in background.

Comment: When you use progress bar , its already become blur .. do u want to make it transparent or what ?

Answer (score 3):

I am using this code as i required same as you, which is best fit to your requirement too.

You can write this code in your base activity class and use it as your requirement.

```
ViewGroup progressView;
protected boolean isProgressShowing = false;

public void showProgressingView() {

    if (!isProgressShowing) {
        isProgressShowing = true;
        progressView = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.progressbar_layout, null);
        View v = this.findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) v;
        viewGroup.addView(progressView);
    }
}

public void hideProgressingView() {
    View v = this.findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) v;
    viewGroup.removeView(progressView);
    isProgressShowing = false;
}
```

here `progressbar_layout.xml` is

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#BA000000">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

- This is simple and neat way to do this.
- You can customize your `progressbar_layout` in any way, any color, any style.
- Get rid of default android progress bar

Comment: How to use it in a plain java class, let's say if I have my login code logic in a separate class which is not an activity?

Comment: @Muhammad then you need to have the activity context.

Comment: I have context but I'm confusing about the show/hide progress bar from the class. Currently, I am passing context and ProgressBar reference to the class. Could you please suggest me a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Put ProgressBar control to your `layout xml`

```
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarDialog"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/myDialog" >
   </ProgressBar>
```

Assign Id into your `activity`

```
    private ProgressBar bar;
    bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBarDialog);
```

Make one xml file named myDialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="360">

    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="8"
        android:useLevel="false">
        <size
            android:width="48dip"
            android:height="48dip" />

        <gradient
            android:centerColor="@color/color_preloader_center"
            android:centerY="0.50"
            android:endColor="@color/color_preloader_end"
            android:startColor="@color/color_preloader_start"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false" />
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

put following code in **colors.xml**

```
 <color name="color_preloader_start">#000000</color>
 <color name="color_preloader_center">#000000</color> 
 <color name="color_preloader_end">#ff56a9c7</color>
```

Comment: I want transperent background

Comment: this will make background transparent. use it.

Comment: Gulnaz- I want only wheel not dialog. and screen should be transperent and progress wheel size should be min

Answer (score 0):

use simple progress bar in your xml
use dependancy

```
compile 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.1.1' in build.gradle
```

give id (content) to your xml which you want to blur during progress bar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

in java copy this blurall() function

```
private void blurall() {


        if (blurred) {
            Blurry.delete((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.content));
        } else {
            long startMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Blurry.with(viewprofile.this)
                    .radius(25)
                    .sampling(2)
                    .async()
                    .animate(500)
                    .onto((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.content));
            Log.d(getString(R.string.app_name),
                    "TIME " + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() - startMs) + "ms");
        }

        blurred = !blurred;


}
```

first time call blurall() function will blur all your screen and second time call blurall() function will remove blur.Call blurall() function before progress bar start like

```
blurall();
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

after that call again blurall() function after

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.Gone);
blurall();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working with this, and it works perfectly for me.

In XML

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/bgBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_trans_overlay"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/loading"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:foregroundGravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

rounded_trans_overlay.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#AAb9ebed"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="0.5dp"
        android:color="#66295A75" />
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />
</shape>
```

in Java have this function

```
public void loading(boolean val, Activity activity, ProgressBar progressBar, View view) {
    if (val) {
        view.setElevation(8);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        activity.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
    } else {
        view.setElevation(0);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        activity.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
    }
}
```

To activate Call

```
loading(true, requireActivity(), binding.loading, binding.bgBox);
```

To deactivate

```
loading(false, requireActivity(), binding.loading, binding.bgBox);
```

Answer (score -1):

simply add this line in your java code

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_
                                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```